# how to use mysql "count" and "group by" to include 0 counts?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm rookie with sql. I have the following table:

| task_name | status |
| --- | --- |
| task_01 | done |
| task_02 | failed |
| task_03 | done |
| task_04 | done |
| task_05 | failed |
| task_06 | done |
| task_07 | failed |
| task_08 | failed |
| task_09 | failed |
| task_10 | done |
| task_11 | done |
| task_12 | failed |
| task_13 | done |
| task_14 | done |

I know that another option for "status" column is "pending", but for now, no row has that status.

So, I want to obtain the count of the status, including the result "pending" to be counted as "0".

I am running:

`SELECT status,count(*) FROM test.data where status in ("done","failed","pending") group by status;`

And the result is:

| status | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| done | 8 |
| failed | 6 |

But the desired output is:

| status | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| done | 8 |
| failed | 6 |
| pending | 0 |

How can I make a query to obtain that result?

Note 1: I can't create another table (like a status_label table)

Note 2: sorry for my english, my native language is spanish

Comment: If there is no row with a status of pending, where is the overall list of tasks? There must be a table with all the tasks listed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH
-- your input ... 
indata(task,status) AS (
            SELECT 'task_01','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_02','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_03','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_04','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_05','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_06','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_07','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_08','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_09','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_10','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_11','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_12','failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_13','done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'task_14','done'
)
,
-- add an in-line three row table with the three statuses
status(status) AS (
            SELECT 'done'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'failed'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'pending'
)
-- left join your in-line table with the base table
-- and count the base table's statuses
SELECT
  status.status
, COALESCE(count(indata.status),0) AS statuscount
FROM status
LEFT JOIN indata USING(status)
GROUP BY status.status;     
 status  | statuscount 
---------+-------------
 pending |           0
 failed  |           6
 done    |           8
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is a UNION query.

```
SELECT status,count(*) FROM test.data group by status;
UNION
SELECT 'pending', 0
```

UNION allows you to combine the output of two identical queries, and even manufacture fake output for a query.

Note: This isn't a robust solution that would be used as a general solution as hard-coding results should be frowned upon, it is the simplest answer to your specific question.